# error: reference to put is ambiguous, both method put(String,Collection) in JSONObject and method put(String,Map) in JSONObject match

Tags: java, json, ambiguous

I trying to use this cordova background services plugin in one of my mobile Apps ( I am using the web based mobile app development platform called Appery io). I have been able to get quite a few cordova / phonegap plugins to work but when I try to add this background services plugin

https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core

And try to build the package I get the following error.

```
/src/com/red_folder/phonegap/plugin/backgroundservice/BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java:[711,16] error: reference to put is ambiguous, both method put(String,Collection) in JSONObject and method put(String,Map) in JSONObject match

/src/com/red_folder/phonegap/plugin/backgroundservice/BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java:[712,16] error: reference to put is ambiguous, both method put(String,Collection) in JSONObject and method put(String,Map) in JSONObject match

/src/com/red_folder/phonegap/plugin/backgroundservice/BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java:[713,16] error: reference to put is ambiguous, both method put(String,Collection) in JSONObject and method put(String,Map) in JSONObject match

/src/com/red_folder/phonegap/plugin/backgroundservice/BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java:[714,16] error: reference to put is ambiguous, both method put(String,Collection) in JSONObject and method put(String,Map) in JSONObject match
```

The lines that cause the problem are ( I have numbered the lines)

            `if (this.mServiceConnected != null && this.mServiceConnected && this.isServiceRunning()) {
                try { result.put("ServiceRunning", true); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding ServiceRunning to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                try { result.put("TimerEnabled", isTimerEnabled()); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding TimerEnabled to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                try { result.put("Configuration", getConfiguration()); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding Configuration to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                try { result.put("LatestResult", getLatestResult()); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding LatestResult to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                try { result.put("TimerMilliseconds", getTimerMilliseconds()); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding TimerMilliseconds to JSONObject failed", ex);};
            } else {
                710. try { result.put("ServiceRunning", false); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding ServiceRunning to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                711. try { result.put("TimerEnabled", null); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding TimerEnabled to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                712. try { result.put("Configuration", null); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding Configuration to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                713. try { result.put("LatestResult", null); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding LatestResult to JSONObject failed", ex);};
                714. try { result.put("TimerMilliseconds", null); } catch (Exception ex) {Log.d(LOCALTAG, "Adding TimerMilliseconds to JSONObject failed", ex);};
            }`

I believe this may have something to do with a previous version of java being used as this bug seems to be similar to

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6199075

I am a total newbie to java so if anyone could help me with some workaround or anything, it'll be great.

Thanks once again,
M&M

Answer (score 1):

Assuming lines 711, 712, 713, 714 are the lines where you put `null`, you need to typecast the `null` to whatever type you're trying to put. Maybe you shouldn't be using `null` at all.

Comment: oke thanks a lot. It does reaffirm something that I had thought about but then me being a toootal noob to java, how do I use the typecast in this scenario? boolean false and string empty - strict datatypes or something?